# PHP Mail function sending messages with wrong time?

Tags: php, email, time

I am using the following code to send a message. The current time is 9:20 PM on my phone, on the server, and on my Mac. I execute this code and I receive and email on my phone. But it says that it got it at 9:23.. Three minutes into the future... How is this happening

```
$to  = 'me@domain.org' . ', '; // note the comma
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Check-in Report <reports@fsbcheck.in>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: 8:23 looks like about 1 hour in the past from 9:20. I would assume your mail server is 1 hour behind or the timezone on one of those is different.

Comment: Oops. Nope 9:23. Corrected up top

Comment: Then your mail server is a couple minutes off.

Comment: I'm using local server for that I believe. Sever time is synced exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That timestamp (9:23) is set when the SMTP server reports sending it. Wherever your outgoing mail server is, the system clock on that machine needs adjusting.